# How do I get returned results when using sequelize and sql template strings when using the like keyword in sql with a passed in parameter?

Tags: sequelize.js

How do I get returned results when using sequelize and sql template strings when using the like keyword in sql with a passed in parameter?
Here is the code I am using:

```
let filteredCode = '%' + code.slice(0, 5) + '%'
            console.log(filteredCode)
            let selectFromFax = SQL`SELECT * FROM Fax WHERE Uid like ${filteredCode} `
            console.log(selectFromFax)
```

And here are the results I am getting:

```
%068c9%
SQLStatement {
strings: [ 'SELECT * FROM Fax WHERE Uid like ', ' ' ],
values: [ '%068c9%' ] }
result of query []
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually does work. Hopefully its helpful for someone using node package sql-template-strings and sequelize.